# Is there any way to increase single group of const by a fixed number rather than 1?

Tags: go, constants, iota

I have a single group of constant:

```
const (
    a = 100
    b = 200
    c = 300
)
```

I was wondering if there is any way to use `iota` keyword instead of assigning each value manually?

As described in the [official reference](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Iota), it is possible to use bitwise shift with iota to increase numbers, but I want to increase by a fixed number like 100 for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```golang
const (
    _ = iota * 100
    a
    b
    c
)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/V-2Uv9JPj6g